# GitHub Actions: Passing JSON data to another job

Tags: bash, github, build, yaml, github-actions

I'm attempting to pass an array of dynamically fetched data from one GitHub Action job to the actual job doing the build. This array will be used as part of a matrix to build for multiple versions. However, I'm encountering an issue when the bash variable storing the array is evaluated.

```
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      versions: ${{ steps.matrix.outputs.value }}
    steps:
      - id: matrix
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y jq && \
          MAINNET=$(curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getVersion"}' | jq '.result["solana-core"]') && \
          TESTNET=$(curl https://api.testnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getVersion"}' | jq '.result["solana-core"]') && \
          VERSIONS=($MAINNET $TESTNET) && \
          echo "${VERSIONS[@]}" && \
          VERSION_JSON=$(echo "${VERSIONS[@]}" | jq -s) && \
          echo $VERSION_JSON && \
          echo '::set-output name=value::$VERSION_JSON'
        shell: bash
      - id: debug
        run: |
          echo "Result: ${{ steps.matrix.outputs.value }}"

  changes:
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Set job outputs to values from filter step
    outputs:
      core: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.core }}
      package: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.package }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        TEST: [buy, cancel, create_auction_house, delegate, deposit, execute_sale, sell, update_auction_house, withdraw_from_fee, withdraw_from_treasury, withdraw]
        SOLANA_VERSION: ${{fromJson(needs.setup.outputs.versions)}}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # For pull requests it's not necessary to checkout the code
      - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
        id: filter
        with:
          filters: |
            core:
              - 'core/**'
            package:
              - 'auction-house/**'
      - name: debug
        id: debug
        working-directory: ./auction-house/program
        run: echo ${{ needs.setup.outputs.versions }}
```

In the `setup` job above, the two versions are evaluated to a bash array (in `VERSIONS`) and converted into a JSON array to be passed to the next job (in `VERSION_JSON`). The last `echo` in the `matrix` step results in a print of `[ "1.10.31", "1.11.1" ]`, but the `debug` step prints out this:

```
Run echo "Result: "$VERSION_JSON""
  echo "Result: "$VERSION_JSON""
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    CARGO_TERM_COLOR: always
    RUST_TOOLCHAIN: stable
Result:
```

The `changes` job also results in an error:

> Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'changes'.
> .github/workflows/program-auction-house.yml (Line: 44, Col: 25): Unexpected type of value '$VERSION_JSON', expected type: Sequence.

It definitely seems like the `$VERSION_JSON` variable isn't actually being evaluated properly, but I can't figure out where the evaluation is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For `echo '::set-output name=value::$VERSION_JSON'` you need to use double quotes or bash would not expand `$VERSION_JSON`.
- `set-output` is not happy with multi-lined data. For your case, you can use `jq -s -c` so the output will be one line.